# If or statement in excel that has 3 options

Tags: excel, function, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to display data from 3 seperate cells in one sheet in a single cell in a different sheet in the same workbook.  I believe it would require an if or statement but not sure how to write it.

Example: if B3 has data, then both B4 and B5 will be blank and the cell in the other sheet will display the B3 data

Example: If B3 is blank, B4 has data and B5 is blank, then the cell in the other sheet would display the B4 data

Example: If B3 is blank, B4 is blank and B5 has data, the cell in the other sheet would display the B5 data

How do I go about writing this function?

Comment: You've been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: You are absolutely correct on showing work. I am at a lose on even where to begin. The three fields are free flowing fields.  The user can enter anything in the fields.  I know how to pass data from one field to another field. =RequestFormB3! but I do not know how to do it for multiple cells and how to determine which field has data and the other two do not.  If you know of a tutorial please share.

Comment: lol you're willfully flaunting the rules. Start with an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something simpler. As whatever process inputs data on those cells seems to already determine data validation you can just concatenate all the cells with spaces added and trim the result. As only one cell is populated at a time from your description then only that cell's data will show on the output cell. It would look something like this:

```
=TRIM(B3&" "&B4&" "&B5)
```

Hope this resolves your concern. Cheers,

Comment: Interesting hack ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who posted solutions.

Here is what I am using and it works.

=RequestForm!B30&RequestForm!B38&RequestForm!B61&RequestForm!B85